# How to download thumbnails of images stored in firebase using glide

Tags: android, firebase-storage, android-glide

I want to download the images thumbnail not the entire image from my firebase storage. I am using glide to load the images but i am not getting how can i load image thumbnails as it will be quicker and memory efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create thumbnails for the images, likely using something like [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) or [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). You can write a function that takes the original image, and runs it through [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), then saves it back to Firebase Storage at a known location, say `images/myImage_resized_<height>_<width>.png`, which your client can then fetch.

Alternatively, you can use Imgix or Cloudinary to serve smaller images stored in Firebase Storage by providing our Download URLs to those services and fetching the images from there. If you're willing to do some more work, Google App Engine offers the [App Engine Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) for free, which does many of the same things.