# Flutter : Preload an image from Firesbase storage before downloading

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to display an image from Firebase storage. But before displaying the original quality, I want to preload the image and display like a thumbail that I use. Is there a way to do it?

I have used `Image.network` and `FadeInImage` but before the image preload, nothing is shown. I want to avoid using a local image as placeholder.

Here is how I load the image to store in local.

```
File _image;
Future getImage() async {
  var storageRef = 
  FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("PICTURES_ITEM").child("SUB_ITEM");
   Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   Directory(appDocDirectory.path+'/PICTURES_FOLDER').create(recursive: true).then((d){
   var file = File('${d.path}/${DateTime.now()}.jpeg');
    StorageFileDownloadTask downloadTask = storageRef.writeToFile(file);
    downloadTask.future.then((ok){
  setState((){
     _image = file; //the _image that I use to display.
  });
  });
 });
}
```

If I don't want to store in local. I do like that

```
 Image.network("image_url_from_firebase_storage")
```

Comment: Hi there, yes it's possible to do this by uploading a thumbnail for each image or using a thumbnail service. Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201695/how-to-download-thumbnails-of-images-stored-in-firebase-using-glide

Comment: Thanks. But I might learn google cloud before doing it While I'm looking for a way like a dart package for that.

Comment: You _must_ have a thumbnail or a thumbnail service, there's not much you can do on the client-side. You cannot display a network image without downloading it.

Comment: @mertcanb do you know a thumbnail service to do it?

Comment: I would recommend setting up a cloud function. Check this out: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/image-thumbnail-resizer-cloud-function/

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm going to try